# Refreshing with Angular 4 repeats current route

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular4-router

I am using Angular 4 in a project I am working on. I don't have much experience with Angular and I am supposed to fix a bug. I think it's pretty easy, but when I load the app and get the `/home` route, if I click the refresh button another `/home` is appended to the URL.

My `RouterModule` config looks like this:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
    /* other paths mapping to components */
    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
])
```

Any ideas for a novice?

Answer (score 1):

I am not able to reproduce this in [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-52685467?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts). The below gif shows how your configuration works as expected for me:

[image]

Please `enableTracing` and post the results so that I can help you more:

```
RouterModule.forRoot(
  appRoutes,
  { enableTracing: true } // <-- insert this here
)
```

One solution is to use absolute redirects (`redirectTo: '/home'`). However, as Viktor Savkin says in his [blog post](https://vsavkin.com/angular-router-understanding-redirects-2826177761fc):

> Local redirects replace a single URL segment with a different one. Absolute redirects replace the whole URL.

But as you are using local redirects here such as `redirectTo: 'home'` it should be replace the current path 'home' with 'home' again and not append it. Does this bug happen only in production or in development as well?

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tried enabling tracing and it seems that it still hits the same path `''` even when the URL is `home/home`. `RoutesRecognized(id: 1, url: '/', urlAfterRedirects: '/home', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'home', path:'home') } )`

Comment: Actually, I think it was `<base href="" />` that caused this. I changed it to `<base href="/" />` according to Angular docs and also removed a second `<base>` tag and now the involuntary repeating is gone. Could this have been the culprit?

Comment: @Viktor I also had this suspicion. it could well have been. Try with and without base href and if it is the cause then write an answer to this question so that others with this problem don't experience the pain you had.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change  from using a string to using the component name

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
    { path: '', redirectTo: HomeComponent , pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
    /* other paths mapping to components */
    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
])
```

Comment: Actually, I tried that and it works. But why? Why can't I redirect `''` to `'home'` and reuse its component definition?

Comment: No it wont, pathMatch: 'full' means, that the whole URL path needs to match and is consumed by the route matching algorithm. use component name instead

Comment: We can use path in redirectTo property instead of component. @Tom is correct

Answer (score 0):

as @Tom mentionned, this worked in my case

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<base href="" /> that caused this. I changed it to <base href="/" />
```

```
// app-routing.module.ts
RouterModule.forRoot([
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  /* other paths mapping to components */
])
```